# List of all US ZIP Codes using uszipcode

Tags: python, web-scraping, zipcode

I've been trying to fetch all US Zipcodes for a web scraping project for my company.
I'm trying to use uszipcode library for doing it automatically rather than manually from the website im intersted in but cant figure it out.

this is my manual attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/50.0.2661.102'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

hrefs = []
all_zipcodes = []

# Extract all
for data in soup.find_all('div', class_='state-list'):
    for a in data.find_all('a'):
        if a is not None:
            hrefs.append(a.get('href'))
hrefs.remove(None)



def get_zipcode_list():
    """
           get_zipcode_list gets the GET response from the web archives server using CDX API
           :return: CDX API output in json format.
        """
    for state in hrefs:
        state_url = url + state
        state_page = requests.get(state_url, headers=headers)
        states_soup = BeautifulSoup(state_page.text, 'html.parser')
        div = states_soup.find(class_='list-group')
        for a in div.findAll('a'):
            if str(a.string).isdigit():
                all_zipcodes.append(a.string)
    return all_zipcodes
```

This takes alot of time and would like to know how to do the same in more efficient way using uszipcodes

Comment: What is the format of data that you require?

Comment: A list of all US zipcodes

Comment: The @luca's answer below should give it to you then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download the list of zip codes from the [official source](https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=94103)) and then parse it if it's for one-time use and you don't need any other metadata associated with each of the zip codes like the one which [uszipcodes](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/index.html) provides.

The uszipcodes also has [another database](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/index.html#id4) which is quite big and should have all the data you need.

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine
zipSearch = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=False)
allZipCodes = zipSearch.by_pattern('', returns=200000)
print(len(allZipCodes)
```

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'simple_zipcode'`

Comment: I am extremely skeptical that your "official source" link to `"http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us"` is truly an official source.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to search by pattern ''

```
s = SearchEngine()
l = s.by_pattern('', returns=1000000)
print(len(l))
```

More details in [docs](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/search.html#uszipcode.search.SearchEngine.by_pattern) and in their [basic tutorial](https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/01-Tutorial/index.html#id5)

Comment: this yields 29973, should be around 40k

Comment: If you add `zipcode_type=None` as an argument, 42724 ZIP codes are returned.  As in: `l = s.by_pattern('', returns=1000000, zipcode_type=None)`

Answer (score 1):

```
engine = SearchEngine()
allzips = {}
for i in range(100000): #Get zipcode info for every possible 5-digit combination
    zipcode = str(i).zfill(5)
    try: allzips[zipcode] = engine.by_zipcode(zipcode).to_dict()
    except: pass
#Convert dictionary to DataFrame
allzips = pd.DataFrame(allzips).T.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Since zip codes are only 5-digits, you can iterate up to 100k and see which zip codes don't return an error. This solution gives you a DataFrame with all the stored information for each saved zip code

Answer (score 0):

The regex that zip code in US have is `[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?`

you can simply check with re module

```
import re
regex = r"[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?"
if re.match(zipcode, regex):
    print("match")
else:
    print("not a match")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get ~42,150 zip codes for a similar project. Wanted to show my work since I used this thread as a jumping off point.

```
import us
from uszipcode import SearchEngine, SimpleZipcode
import os

#Creates a txt file named "zips" with zipcodes
#sorted by state then density

states = [state.name for state in us.states.STATES]
states.append('Washington DC')
engine = SearchEngine()
convertedList = ""

with open("zips.txt", "w") as f:

    for i in states:
        zipcodes = engine.query(state=i, sort_by=SimpleZipcode.population_density, zipcode_type=None, returns=50000)
        print(i, len(zipcodes))
        for i in zipcodes:
            convertedList += i.zipcode + ", "

    print("Total Zipcodes = ", "{:,}".format(len(convertedList)//7))
    f.write(convertedList)

f.close()

#Remove trailing comma
with open("zips.txt", 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    f.truncate()
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all ZIP codes like this:

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine

sr = SearchEngine()
zipcodes = sr.by_coordinates(42, -71, radius=300000000, returns=0, zipcode_type=None)
```

By default, query functions only return STANDARD zipcodes. If you want all zipcode types, you should set `zipcode_type=None`. Setting `returns=0` removes the limit on the number of returned results.

As a result, you get a list of 42724 elements.